# Limiting initial size of an Azure Storage container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to know if there's a way to create an Azure storage container of a specific size, say 20 gb. I know it can be created without any restriction (I think up to 200 TB?), but can it be created with a specific size? What if I need that kind of set up? Like giving a user 20 gb initially, then at a later time increasing it to, say 50? Is that possible?

Like, how do I create that boundary/limitation for a new user that signs up my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the service by itself. This should be a feature implemented in your app.

Comment: So something at the client side? How do I do that? Like, what's the logic? I can't think of anything TBH.

Comment: You should have some kind of service or backend that deals will this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer, it is not possible to do with Blob Storage at the service level and you will have to implement your own logic to calculate the size of the blob container.

If restricting container size is the most important feature you are after, you may want to look at [`Azure File Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction). Equivalent to a blob container is a `File Share` there and you can set the quota for a File Share and change it dynamically. The quota of a File Share can be any value between 1GB - 5TB (100TB in case of Premium File Storage account) at the time of writing this answer.

Azure File Storage and Blob Storage are somewhat similar but they are meant to serve different purposes. However for simple object storage purposes you can use either of the two (File Storage is more expensive that Blob Storage though).